# ExtJS problem with Extended Window, shows in FF not in IE

Tags: firefox, extjs, internet-explorer, window, extend

I get this irritating error message in IE, 'Events is empty or not an object'.

This is my Extended window:

```
windowKandidaatInfo = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
id: 'windowKandidaatInfo',
title: 'Kandidaatinfo',
border: true,
bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
layout: 'fit',
width: 800,
height: 600,
pers_id: 0,
modal: true,
viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
constructor: function(pers_id){
    this.pers_id = pers_id;
    windowKandidaatInfo.superclass.constructor.call(this);
},
activeTab: function(panel, tab){
    tab.getForm().load({
        url: '/kandidaten/get_kandidaat_info/' + panel.pers_id + '/',
        method: 'get'
    });
    tab.getForm().on({
        actioncomplete: function(form, event){
            if(event.type == "load"){
                //Data loaded
            }
        }
    })
},
spacerCol: {
    colspan: 2,
    border: true,
    width: 1,
    height: 25,
    align: 'left'
},
combCountry: {
    xtype: 'combo',
    name:'land',
    fieldLabel: 'Land',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/index/get_countries/',
        method: 'get',
        root: 'data',
        fields: [{name:'id'},{name:'naam'}],
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    displayField: 'naam',
    valueField: 'id',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    typeAhead: true
},
combGeslacht: {
    xtype: 'combo',
    name:'geslacht',
    fieldLabel: 'Geslacht',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/index/get_geslacht/',
        method: 'get',
        root: 'data',
        fields: [{name:'naam'}],
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    displayField: 'naam',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    typeAhead: true
},
combBurgelijkeStaat: {
    xtype: 'combo',
    name:'burgelijke_staat',
    fieldLabel: 'Burgelijke staat',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/index/get_burgelijke_staat/',
        method: 'get',
        root: 'data',
        fields: [{name:'naam'}],
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    displayField: 'naam',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    typeAhead: true
},
combProfessions: {
    xtype: 'combo',
    name:'beroep',
    fieldLabel: 'Beroep',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/index/get_beroepen/',
        method: 'get',
        root: 'data',
        fields: [{name:'beroep'}],
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    displayField: 'beroep',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    typeAhead: true
},
initComponent: function(){

    Ext.apply(this, {
       items: new Ext.TabPanel({
           id: 'tabGeneral',               
           pers_id: this.pers_id,
           activeTab: 0,
           items: [
               {
                    title: 'Algemene info',
                    layout: 'table',
                    xtype: 'form',
                    frame: true,
                    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
                    viewConfig: {columns: 2, forceFit: true},
                    items: [
                        {
                            column: .5,
                            width: 400,
                            layout: 'form',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    layout: 'table',
                                    columns: 2,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            layout: 'form',
                                            style: 'margin-right: 5px;',
                                            items: [
                                                { xtype: 'textfield', width: 40, name: 'voorletters', fieldLabel: 'Voorl/ voornaam'},
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            layout: 'form',
                                            items: [
                                                { xtype: 'textfield', width: 200, name: 'voornaam', hideLabel: true}
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'achternaam', fieldLabel: 'Achternaam'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'adres', fieldLabel: 'Adres'},
                                {
                                    layout: 'table',
                                    columns: 2,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            layout: 'form',
                                            style: 'margin-right: 5px;',
                                            items:[
                                                {xtype:'textfield', width: 60, name:'postcode', fieldLabel:'Postcode/ plaats'}
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            layout: 'form',                                                
                                            items: [
                                                {xtype:'textfield', width: 200, name:'plaats', hideLabel: true}
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                this.combCountry,
                                this.spacerCol,
                                { xtype: 'textfield', value: '1900-01-01', format: 'Y-m-d', name: 'geb_datum', fieldLabel: 'Geb. datum'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'bsn_nummer', fieldLabel: 'Bsn nummer'},
                                this.combProfessions,
                                this.spacerCol,
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'bedrijfsnaam', fieldLabel: 'Bedrijfsnaam'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'kvk_naam', fieldLabel: 'KvK naam'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'kvk_land', fieldLabel: 'KvK land'}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            column: .5,
                            width: 400,
                            layout: 'form',
                            items: [
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'telefoon', fieldLabel: 'Telefoon'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'mobiel', fieldLabel: 'Mobiel'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'fax', fieldLabel: 'Fax'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', width: 200, name: 'email', fieldLabel: 'E-mail'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', width: 200, name: 'website', fieldLabel: 'Website'},
                                this.spacerCol,
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'geb_plaats', fieldLabel: 'Geb. plaats'},
                                this.combBurgelijkeStaat,
                                this.combGeslacht,
                                this.spacerCol,
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'btw_nummer', fieldLabel: 'BTW nummer'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'kvk_plaats', fieldLabel: 'KvK plaats'},
                                { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'kvk_nummer', fieldLabel: 'KvK nummer'}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
               },
               {
                    title: 'Adres info',
                    xtype: 'form',
                    layout: 'form',
                    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;'
               },
               {
                    title: 'Contact info',
                    xtype: 'form',
                    layout: 'form',
                    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;'
               }
           ],
           listeners: {
               tabchange: this.activeTab
           }
       })
    });
    windowKandidaatInfo.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
},
show: function(){
    windowKandidaatInfo.superclass.show.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

});

this is how i call it in a simple JS function:

```
function showWindow(){
var win = new windowKandidaatInfo(id);
if(win){
    win.show();
}}
```

Why o why is it showing in FF but not in IE?

Comment: IE interprets [a,b,c,] as an array with 4 elements that its 4th element is undefined while all other browsers treat that as an array with 3 elements. So usually a trailing comma in arrays leads to unexpected behavior in IE. However in your code, as @BrennaSoft has pointed to, you seam to have an extra comma in your object definition which to the best of my knowledge is unaccepted in FF too. Having said that, FF might have code to handle such exceptional cases while IE probably doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma on this line.

```
{ xtype: 'textfield', width: 40, name: 'voorletters', fieldLabel: 'Voorl/ voornaam'},
```

Firefox is very forgiving with JS syntax where IE isn't. Most of your issues will also probably be due to extra commas. To combat this, I do commas at the beginning of new lines instead of at the end.

So it would be like this.

```
windowKandidaatInfo = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
id: 'windowKandidaatInfo'
,title: 'Kandidaatinfo'
,border: true
,bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;'
,layout: 'fit'
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the extra comma, but -1 for recommending code mutilation as a long-term solution.  So there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your code a bit, there are a few missing semicolons (http://www.jslint.com/).

I worked with extjs some time ago, and had the same problem with a window rendering in Firefox and not in IE. Maybe IE's JS engine is more sensitive to syntactical errors.